# How to create a Component on Click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm relatively new to React and I am trying to create a web application that creates the Rnd component when I click a button. When I click the button I can only get it to create one Rnd component even though it still registers all the clicks. Any help would be great.

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Rnd from 'react-rnd';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  renderWidget() {

    console.log('I was clicked');

    const widget = React.createElement(Rnd, {default: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 200}, className: 'box'}, React.createElement('p', {}, this.state.text));

    ReactDOM.render(
      widget,
      document.getElementById('widget')
    );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <section className='hero is-dark'>
          <div className='hero-body'>
            <div className='container'>
              <h1 className='title'>
                Dashboard
              </h1>
              <h2 className='subtitle'>
                At A Glance Data
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className='section'>
          <div className='container has-text-right'>
            <h2 className='subtitle'>
              Create New Widget
            </h2>
            <button className='button is-dark is-outlined' onClick={this.renderWidget.bind(this)}>
              <span className='icon'>
                <i className='fas fa-plus'></i>
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id='widget'>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's the proper way to do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/91x4rkkn5r You're not supposed to render the DOM inside your class, and you need to read up on `state` and the like.

Comment: Thanks all of that is really helpful.

Comment: @Atomator, did you find my answer useful? Please upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnKennedy, I did upvote it but I don't have enough reputation for it to show up publicly.

Comment: @Atomator, you might want to accept it as the correct answer. This will be reflected publicly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have possibility to run your code but at quick glance I would probably not use ReactDOM.render to render new component every time the button is clicked. Instead I'd add array e.g. "generatedComponents" to the App-component's state and every time you click the button, it would add a new component to that array. Then you render the components in that array at the App-components render method.

Also I wouldn't use variable type **const** in the renderWidget-function, but instead **let** or **var**.

Comment: `const` is fine here; it's local and gone anyway as soon as the function finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could go about doing what you want:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Rnd from "react-rnd";

const Widget = () => <p>Hello World</p>;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      components: [],
      text: "Hello to you"
    };
  }

  renderWidget() {
    console.log("I was clicked");

    const newComponents = [...this.state.components, Widget];

    this.setState({
      components: newComponents
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { components } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="hero is-dark">
          <div className="hero-body">
            <div className="container">
              <h1 className="title">Dashboard</h1>
              <h2 className="subtitle">At A Glance Data</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container has-text-right">
            <h2 className="subtitle">Create New Widget</h2>
            <button
              className="button is-dark is-outlined"
              onClick={this.renderWidget.bind(this)}
            >
              <span className="icon">
                <i className="fas fa-plus" />
                Click me
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            {components.length !== 0 &&
              components.map((Widget, i) => <Widget key={i} />)}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("widget"));
```

[image: Edit xlknzw4yr4]

Comment: `componets.length !== 0` is redundant it can just be `components.length` nice answer though

Comment: Thanks @Omar for pointing that out. I did it that way to avoid unexpected surprises. You're right it can be done that way too.